# How to extract information from a particular form of data types?

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner of Haskell and I have a question.
I created my own type:

```hs
data OwnType = OwnType (Int, Int, Int) (Int, Int, Int, Int)
deriving (Read, Show)
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to extract information from my `OwnType`.
I know this is possible to extract information from a type like this:

```hs
data OwnTypeEasy = OwnTypeEasy Int Int

getFirstInt :: OwnTypeEasy -> Int
getFirstInt (first _) = first
```

But I don't know how to extract data from OwnType.
I tried this:

```hs
getFirstElementOfFirstTuple :: OwnType -> Int
getFirstElementOfFirstTuple ((a _ _), (_ _ _ _)) = a
```

But it's not working..

--
To get an OwnType object I'm just converting a string to OwnType using this:

```
parseType :: ReadS OwnType
parseType s = reads $ "OwnType "++s
```

Comment: You forgot the data constructor, it is `getFirstElementOfFirstTuple (OwnType (a, _, _) (_, _, _, _)) = a`

Comment: Your simpler example doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data OwnType = OwnType (Int,Int,Int) (Int,Int,Int)
```

Pattern matching is always the answer.  Your example - both the one you said you know works and the one you are having trouble with - lacks a constructor.

Try:

```
getFirstElementOfFirstTuple (OwnType (a, _, _) (_, _, _)) = a
```

Credit to @WillemVanOnsem